# Subdomain mobile site is not displaying on iPhones

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

The html5 website configuration is a stand-alone desktop with redirect to subdomain mobile website, sitemap shows this and also have a mobile sitemap both in the root directory. Mobile site has no jQuery or scripts.

I am told by my client the mobile website will not load on an iPhone. When my client has it bookmarked on their iPhone it functions fully, but when directing clients to the website it will not come up.

Error reads: Misdirected Request. The client needs a new connection for this request as the requested host name does not match the Servicer Name Indication (SNI) in use for this connection. My server is Linux.

Sitemap:

```
`<url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/index.html</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-11-09</lastmod>
        <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.9</priority>
        <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            media="only screen and (max-width: 750px)"
            href="https://m.example.com/index.html" />
</url>`
```

Desktop page head tag:
`<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 750px)" href="https://m.example.com/abrecht-bracket-sloped-ceiling.html" />`

Mobile does have a canonical tag in the head:
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/abrecht-bracket-sloped-ceiling.html" />`

Thank you for any help.

I have been searching with results how the user can change their iPhone.

On Stackoverflow many have the reverse issue, trying to stop/block a subdomain, or using an iPhone as a local device.